# How to properly connect to database in vb

Tags: sql-server, vba, visual-studio-2015

I need help on my codes and/or connection.I'm getting an error that says:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll**

**Additional information: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.**

In this code:(Line 4)

```
cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName FROM tblMembers WHERE ID = @ID"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows() Then
        With dr
            .Read()
            txtLname.Text = dr("LastName")
            txtFname.Text = dr("FirstName")
        End With
    End If
```

But if I try to open the connection. This happens.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll**

**Additional information: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.**

With this code:(Line 1)

```
 cn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName FROM tblMembers WHERE ID = @ID"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows() Then
        With dr
            .Read()
            txtLname.Text = dr("LastName")
            txtFname.Text = dr("FirstName")
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim cn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim Process_Id As String
    Dim Processname As String

    connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=PassWord"

    cn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    cn.Open()

    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Process_Id,Processname FROM  dbo.Process_Master where Process_Id = @ID", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = "21"

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows() Then

        With dr.Read()

            Process_Id = dr("Process_Id")
            Processname = dr("Processname")

        End With
    End If
```

Comment: You posted a bunch of code. And yet... you never pointed out the issue to the OP.

Comment: Nevermind. Already solved the problem with a few tweaks. Thanks anyway